# Error en Login a Web con Facebook en PHP

Tags: php, web, login, facebook, facebook-api

Creo haber configurado la aplicación correctamente, no obstante, me arroja el siguiente error al intentar hacer el login.

ERROR: No se puede cargar la URL: El dominio de esta URL no está incluido en los dominios de la aplicación. Para poder cargar esta URL, agrega todos los dominios y subdominios de tu aplicación en el campo "Dominios de la aplicación" en la configuración de la aplicación.

Como se aprecia en las imágenes adjuntas, el dominio indicado está añadido en el campo correspondiente.

Gracias por la ayuda.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Asi poco te podemos ayudar si no pones còdigo, cuando creas el objeto $fb y le pasas la apikey y el id tienes que pasarle el callback tambien, y tiene que ser el mismo, pon el codigo para ayudarte mas concretamente

Comment: A mi me ocurre lo mismo, desde el 17 de marzo no se puede desactivar el modo estricto, además estando añadidos los dominios correctos sigue sin funcionar, cuando antes de esta fecha los hacía correctamente.

Comment: paso 1: use  https en todo
paso 2: configuración de la aplicación faceboook-> configuración básica-> agregue su dominio o subdominio
paso 3: configuración de inicio de sesión de la aplicación faceboook-> URI de redireccionamiento de OAuth válido-> agregue su url de redireccionamiento después de iniciar sesión
paso 4: configuración de la aplicación faceboook-> configuración avanzada-> Administrador de dominio-> agregar su nombre de dominio

Answer (score 5):

Solucionado

Tuve que desactivar el modo estricto de redirecciones
Con lo cual además tuve que agregar la URI de redireccionamiento de OAuth válidos

Adjunto imagen con los cambios

[image]

Comment: Bien, ahora me funciona. Alguien podría decir que problemas puede acarrear desactivar esta opción?

Comment: Es mejor listar las url en el campo, y dejar el modo estricto, facebook tarde que temprano lo va a obligar

Comment: A mi aun me sale ese error a pesar de que hice las configuraciones que indicaron, al parecer facebook otra vez cambio su algoritmo y restringuio los dominios.
Debe ser alguna actualización que realizaron ayer (17 de Marzo 2018), porque la semana pasada estaba funcionando bien.

Answer (score 0):

Yo resolví el mismo error agregando las variables GET a los **URI de Redireccionamiento de OAuth válidos**.

Si revisamos el url de la página de Facebook que nos muestra el mesaje de error cuando tratamos de hacer login, veremos al final la URL que realmente está llamando nuestra aplicación. En mi caso la llamada incluía al final "**?hauth_done=Facebook**" dado que estoy usando **[Hybridauth](https://hybridauth.github.io/)** para realizar el proceso de autentificación.

Hace unos meses, la interfaz de Facebook no permitía agregar variables GET a las URIS válidas. Ahora lo permite y problema resuelto.

Espero les ayude para mantener activado el *switch* de **Usar modo estricto para URI de redireccionamiento**.

Comment: Sería bueno que explicaras mejor tu solución incluyendo un ejemplo. Por ejemplo, ¿se debe colocar domain.com/path1/?var1=value1 ó domain.com/path1/?var1?