# Error Inicio de Sesión SDK Facebook PHP

Tags: php, facebook-api

Al parecer mi configuración en la aplicación y el código PHP están correctos, pero al intentar iniciar sesión me aparece el siguiente mensaje:

[image]

He leído buscando en google que dirigiendome en mi aplicación --> productos --> Inicio de sesión con Facebook --> Configuración, debo desactivar la casilla "Usar modo estricto para URI de redireccionamiento" sin embargo ese input esta chekeado y deshabilitado, no puedo modificar ese valor ni actualizarlo.

Que otra alternativa podría aplicar para resolver el problema?

Comment: Tienes que poner tu codigo para revisar el problema

Comment: A mi me pasa lo mismo desde el día 17 de marzo, la casilla de modo estricto no se puede deshabilitar y a pesar de estar añadidos los dominios de aplicación sigue saliendo ese error.

Comment: posible duplicado https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/111806/error-en-login-a-web-con-facebook-en-php